# Can you use integer arrays as unique dictionary keys?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having trouble using a visual basic Integer() as the key to a dictionary. I am having a problem where even if I pass the ContainsKey() an array with the same values as a existing key it returns false. I think this might be because ContainKey() checks if the object in memory is the same not if they are equal. Correct? I have the following code structure:

```
Dim RGB(3) As Integer
Dim dic as Dictonary(Of Integer(), Double())

...
...

If dic.ContainsKey(RGB) Then 'This never returns true
            meritValue = (MerirtLookUpAVG(RGB)(0) * MerirtLookUpAVG(RGB)(1) + meritValue) / MerirtLookUpAVG(RGB)(0) + 1
      MerirtLookUpAVG(RGB)(0) += 1
      MerirtLookUpAVG(RGB)(1) = meritValue
Else
  MeirtLookUpAVG.Add(RGB, {1, meritValue} 
EndIf
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `System.Drawing.Color` to store the data instead of a integer array? All you would need to do is use [`Color.FromArgb(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) and pass in your 3 values.

Comment: yes but I can't in this part of the code because I am sending them into some math functions that take arrays.

Comment: Mutable objects shouldn't be used as a key in Dictionary

Comment: To elaborate on what Sriram Sakthivel said, if you change one of the elements of `RGB` after it has been added to the dictionary it will break your dictionary. While a object resides inside the dictionary as a key its value (with respect to the `IEqualityComparer` being used on it) must not change. Using a struct like `Color` instead of an array as a key prevents stuff like this from happening as you can not edit the object once it has been created, only replace it with a new one. For the functions that expect arrays just write two functions that converts `Color` to `Integer` array and back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use the [constructor for Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) which accepts a custom `IEqualityComparer(Of T)` for your key type.

Arrays, without a custom [`IEqualityComparer(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), are not valid object types as keys to a dictionary (or other hash-based collection).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the use of IEqualityComparer(Of T). I am creating a custom class that implements the interface and it has Equals1(...) as Boolen and GetHasCode(...) as Integer() when are each called?

Comment: @AlexanderVanAtta That's essentially what it is - you need a custom class that implements Equals and GetHashCode properly for how you want the array comparison to work.  Remember, any two objects which are Equal must provide the same hash code, too...

Comment: @AlexanderVanAtta The problem is there's no single definition of "equals" for an array - do you want 2 arrays to be equal if they contain the same numbers?  Does order matter? etc...

Comment: Order does mater. I am a little confused about what I should put in the GetHashCode() definition. You say if two object are equal they must produce the same hash code. But must any two equal hash codes necessarily have been created by equal objects? ie. Must it be a 1 to 1 mapping?

Comment: @AlexanderVanAtta No - 2 equal objects must produce the same hash code - but 2 different objects can share a hash.